# escaping characters in global.sls (SALT)

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to apply a value in my global.sls with special character ' as follow:

```
testvalues:
  myvalue: 'testvalue'
```

When pillar getting this value I get

```
testvalue
```

insteed of expecting

```
'testvalue'
```

How can I escape the character ' ?

Trying with "'testvalue'" also results in

```
testvalue
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can escape single quote marks in a single quoted string in twice:

```
testvalues:
  myvalue: '''testvalue'''
```

Or you could enclose them in a double quoted string:

```
testvalues:
  myvalue: "'testvalue'"
```